# How to build boost python 3.4 shared libraries for win8.1 64 bit with msvc 10.0

Tags: python, windows, boost, 64-bit

I am trying to build boost python for python 3.4 64 libraries because i need them in order to build http://dlib.net/ python bindings 
My setup is as follows:
MSVC 12.0 is installed
python3.4 64 bit is installed
i downloaded the newest boost 1.57
I am able to compile static libraries, but when i try to link dynamic libraries the program fails.

my project-config.jam looks like this

```
import option ; 

using msvc : 10.0 ;
using python : 3.4 : C:\\Python34 ;

option.set keep-going : false ;
```

In order to compile static libraries even for 64 bit i my bjam looks like this

```
.\bjam.exe --adress-model=64 --with-python variant=release link=static --build-type=complete
```

this works find

when i try build shared libraries I get an error for this command:

```
.\bjam.exe --adress-model=64 --with-python variant=release link=shared --build-type=complete
```

---

```
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll
bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\numeric.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"   @"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll.rsp"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi>boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.dll...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi>boost_python-vc100-mt-1_57.lib...
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll
bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\numeric.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST /subsystem:console /out:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\libs"   @"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll.rsp"
        if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

...failed msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi>boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.dll...
...skipped <pstage\lib>boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-10.0\release\threading-multi>boost_python3-vc100-mt-1_57.lib...
...failed updating 4 targets...
...skipped 4 targets... </code>
```

clear vcvars bat is getting called with x86 argument, i assume the mistake is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... of course now I found the mistake
--adress-model doesn't give a mistake it is simply ignored
also address is spelled with two "d" 5 hours wasted

if someone is looking how to build it, for me this worked:

```
.\bjam.exe --with-python address-model=64 variant=release link=shared --build-type=complete
```